# Loop through has many through relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, for-loop, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Post model and then a Reference model that serves as a model for the relationship between two Posts.  So a single Post (say, POST A) will have some 'referred' posts (POST B, POST C, etc) that it referred to... and it will also have some 'referring' posts (POST D, POST E, etc) that referred to it. From POST A's 'show' view, I am simply trying to loop through and show all 'referred' Posts and all 'referring' posts above and below it.  I want to use the reference relationships model to do this. The references & referred_relationships/referring_relationships are created successfully when a post is created, but I cannot figure out the correct code to place in the view to show these related post titles in a list...any help would be appreciated on what the for each loop mentioned below should look like:

Reference.rb

```
class Reference < ApplicationRecord 
  belongs_to :referred, class_name: "Post"
  belongs_to :referring, class_name: "Post"
  validates :referred_id, presence: true
  validates :referring_id, presence: true
end
```

Post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :referred_relationships, foreign_key: "referred_id", 
                                  class_name:  "Reference",
                                  dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :referred, through: :referred_relationships, source: :referred

  has_many :referring_relationships, foreign_key: "referring_id", 
                                  class_name:  "Reference",
                                  dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :referring, through: :referring_relationships, source: :referring
end
```

Posts_Controller.rb

```
def show
  @title = "Post Profile"
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :referred_id)
end
```

Posts/show.html.erb (Posts profile page)

```
WHAT CODE WOULD GO HERE TO LOOP THROUGH REFERRING POSTS SHOWING POST TITLES???

<div class="postA">              
     <!-- Title -->
    <h2>
      Post <%= @post.id %>
    </h2>

    !-- Content -->
    <p class="text-muted">
      "<%= @post.title %>"
    </p>
</div>

WHAT CODE WOULD GO HERE TO LOOP THROUGH REFERRED POSTS SHOWING POST TITLES???
```

UPDATE:

Thanks I've tried what you suggested as seen below:

```
 <% if @post.referred.any? %>

            <div class="card">

            <% @referred.each do |referred_post| %>
              <p><%= referred_post.title %></p>
            <% end %>

              <br clear="all">

            </div>

      <% else %>

            <p>no relationships exist</p>

     <% end %>
```

But unfortunately it is only showing the original posts title looped for each relationship (as opposed to the title of the referring or referred post.

So it just loops through the original post's title as seen here:

- Post A
- Post A
- Post A

UPDATE 2:

Schema.rb:

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "url"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"
  end

create_table "references", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "referred_id"
    t.integer "referring_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["referred_id", "referring_id"], name: "index_references_on_referred_id_and_referring_id", unique: true
    t.index ["referred_id"], name: "index_references_on_referred_id"
    t.index ["referring_id"], name: "index_references_on_referring_id"
  end
```

Comment: Better if you post the relevant part of your tables. Anyway, does `@post.referred.posts.inspect` return anything?

Comment: No @post.referred.posts.inspect doesn't return anything (at least in the rails console).  What do you mean by my tables...would you just like to see the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller you can load the related records into an instance variable and then loop through them from the controller.

controller:

```
def show
  @title = "Post Profile"
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @referring = @post.referring
  @referred = @post.referred
end
```

view:

```
<ul>
<% @referring.each do |referring_post| %>
  <li><%= referring_post.title %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

You can do the same thing with `@referred`.

Comment: sorry I edited your answer by accident instead of my original post...but hopefully that makes sense.  I've added the controller code you mentioned also.

Comment: I also added my update to the original post because editing your answer can't be seen by anyone until its 'peer reviewed'.  But this loop doesn't seem to bring back the correct titles as I've described.  appreciate the help.

Comment: marking this correct Max...(I just had my column names messed up in my models which was throwing me off).